# Array of string management

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, asp.net-core

I have an array of string, I want to take all the string in an interval of this array until string does not contains something.

Something like:

```
string [] arrayReading = {
  "e","x","a","takefromhere",
  "keeptaking","keeptaking","dont'ttakefromhere","m","p","l","e"
};
```

I have tried:

```
        List<string> result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayReading.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arrayReading[i].Contains("takefromhere"))
            {
                result.Add(arrayReading[i]);

                if (!arrayReading[i + 1].Contains("dont'ttakefromhere"))
                {
                    result.Add(arrayReading[i + 1]);

                    if (!arrayReading[i + 2].Contains("dont'ttakefromhere"))
                    {
                        rescription.Add(arrayReading[i + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Seems working but it's not really dynamic as I want it, because maybe I need to take 20 values between "takefromhere" and "don'ttakefromhere".

Comment: So you will always have a start value right, what about and end value, will there always be one or not? If there's no end value, just take them all or otherwise in between them correct?

Comment: `List<string> result = arrayReading.SkipWhile(item => item != startItem).TakeWhile(item => item != stopItem).ToList();` and you'll have `{"takefromhere", "keeptaking", "keeptaking"}`

Comment: LINQ's `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` allow you to almost translate your specification literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *querying* you can try *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 List<string> result = arrayReading
   .SkipWhile(item => item != "takefromhere") 
   .TakeWhile(item => item != "dont'ttakefromhere")
   .ToList();
```

Or if you want good old *loop* solution:

```
 List<string> result = new List<string>(); 

 bool taking = false;

 foreach (string item in arrayReading) {
   if (!taking) 
     taking = item == "takefromhere";

   if (taking) {
     if (item == "dont'ttakefromhere")
       break;

     result.Add(item);
   } 
}
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join("; ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
takefromhere; keeptaking; keeptaking
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know this property SkipWhile/TakeWhile!

Comment: @RobNone they are not properties... Also this answer *could* address what the OP is doing wrong in their code above so user understands what is wrong and anyone else that may come across the same issue, but this deviates from that by providing a different solution.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: or we could have a new answer that addresses what the OP is doing wrong, and you could even be the one to write that. :-)